# Supersized Slider on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, supersized

I bought a template from themeforest. This is using supersized slider. I want to handle it's change event. But i couldn't find any documentation about this.

Here is the link :

http://demo-limpidthemes.com/Themeforest/html/cruise-demo/light/index.html

And how its call :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/global/plugins/supersized.3.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

Here is implementation :

```
var sliderSettings = function () {

        "use strict";
        $.supersized({

            //Functionality
            slideshow               :   1,      //Slideshow on/off
            autoplay                :   1,      //Slideshow starts playing automatically
            start_slide             :   1,      //Start slide (0 is random)
            random                  :   0,      //Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
            slide_interval          :   10000,  //Length between transitions
            transition              :   1,      //0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
            transition_speed        :   500,    //Speed of transition
            new_window              :   1,      //Image links open in new window/tab
            pause_hover             :   0,      //Pause slideshow on hover
            keyboard_nav            :   0,      //Keyboard navigation on/off
            performance             :   1,      //0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
            image_protect           :   1,      //Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

            //Size & Position
            min_width               :   0,      //Min width allowed (in pixels)
            min_height              :   0,      //Min height allowed (in pixels)
            vertical_center         :   1,      //Vertically center background
            horizontal_center       :   1,      //Horizontally center background
            fit_portrait            :   1,      //Portrait images will not exceed browser height
            fit_landscape           :   0,      //Landscape images will not exceed browser width

            //Components
            navigation              :   1,      //Slideshow controls on/off
            thumbnail_navigation    :   1,      //Thumbnail navigation
            slide_counter           :   1,      //Display slide numbers
            slide_captions          :   1,      //Slide caption (Pull from "title" in slides array)
            slides                  :   slidesObj       //Slideshow Images
        });
    };
```

How can i know, when the slide change ?

Comment: Contact the owner of the template via themeforest, you should get some help from there...

Comment: @Morgs i tried to contact, but didn't response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you take a look on `beforeSlide` & `afterAnimation` events ?

I think its supported since 3.1.3

https://github.com/buildinternet/supersized/pull/7